# Eclipse RCP: command line argument without starting application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application that I had started in 3.x and now I have done a soft migration into 4.x.

I need to add command line argument options for the end-user such as -version, -help etc. So when the user types `myApp -version` in the console, it will NOT start the application, just display the version number.

Thank you!

I tried this out in my Application class,

```
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        String[] args = Platform.getCommandLineArgs();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < args.length)
        {
            if (args[i].equals("-v"))
            {
                System.out.println("Version ABC");
                return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
            }
            i++;
        }

        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        try {
            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            else
                return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        } finally {
            display.dispose();
        }

    }
```

It doesn't start the UI but it starts the splash screen. Is there a method where I can place `getCommandLineArgs()` which is before the start of the splash screen?

SplashHandler Attempt: I tried to bind my own SplashHandler but I hit the same problem. By the time I reach the SplashHandler's init method, the shell with the splash image is already displayed and I think this shell is created before any of my classes can have a change to intervene.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the 4.x docs, but it *APPEARS* that you can use the [start method in IApplication](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplication.html#start%28org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext%29) to handle this before the GUI starts.

Then do something like this in before the application actually starts ...

```
Map args = context.getArguments();

String[] parms_ = (String[]) args.get("application.args");
List parms = Arrays.asList(parms_);

if (parms.contains("-version")) {
    System.out.println("version found");
    return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. I just tried that as well but like I said the splash screen still displays.

Comment: Yeah, the splash screen does display ... don't think there's anything you can do about (except, maybe, not use a splash screen?).

Comment: haha thanks but unfortunately removing the splash screen is not an option at the moment

Answer (score 1):

The splash screen is shown by the launcher (typical eclipse.exe or similar) *before* the Java VM is stated at all. The splash screen is shown based on the entry `osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/...` in `configuration/config.ini`.

You only way out is to

1. remove this entry from `config.ini`
2. show you own splash screen in `IApplication.start(...)`

Please note that the splash screen will be "delayed" compared with today, and the `SplashHandler` will not be instantiated and invoked automatically (though you can do it youself).

Comment: So would the splashscreen by Java be usable in this situation - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: You need a SWT solution, not one based on Swing.